# Set img URL into CardView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, material-design, android-cardview

Hello I am using this library :
https://github.com/DenisMondon/material-design-library

Does anyone know how I can programatilly set image uri, url into this :

```
<com.blunderer.materialdesignlibrary.views.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:mdl_title="CardView"
        app:mdl_description="A Left Image CardView"
        app:mdl_normalButton="Normal"
        app:mdl_highlightButton="Highlight"
        app:mdl_imagePosition="left"
        app:mdl_image="@drawable/image" />
```

it only has a option for : `mCardView.setImageResource();`

I need to use like Image View : `mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

read the source code, you can see:

```
public void setImageResource(int imageResource) {
    mImage = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);

    refresh();
}
```

so you can add a method in its cardview:

```
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
    mImage =new BitmapDrawable(bmp);

    refresh();
}
```

Comment: That mean I have to add this to CardView library. I just imported the library via gradle.  <compile 'com.blunderer:materialdesignlibrary:2.0.0'> - So that means I have to import it as a module to be able to edit it ?

Comment: @Joolah copy the source code, add to your project, you can also use reflection to do this work.